# strings c++ lake of experience

Tags: c++, string

i'm trying to edit contacts on a list that their numbers change and i use temp string for that but at the step of getting the temp string from user it crashes and i don't know the reason maybe lake of experience of me is the reason here is the samples

Sample Input:
3
Abdelrahman Elgammal +1(202)417-0330
Cook Door 16999
Ahmed Naguib 0123456789
2
AbdelRahman ElGammal +1(305)951-1169 
Ahmed Naguib 0020123456788

Sample Output:
AbdelRahman ElGammal +1(305)951-1169 
Cook Door 16999 
Ahmed Naguib 0020123456788
and here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;


struct contact
{
    string first_name;
    string last_name;
    string phone_number;
};
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int n,m,i;
    cin>>n;
    vector <struct contact> contacts(n);
    string temp_first;
    string temp_last;
    string new_phone;
   for(i=0;i<contacts.size();i++)
    {
    cin>>contacts[i].first_name;
    cin>>contacts[i].last_name;
    cin>>contacts[i].phone_number;
    }
   cin>>m;
   for(int j=1;j<=m;j++)
    {
      cin>>temp_first;
      cin>>temp_last;
      cin>>new_phone;
      for(int k=0;k<contacts.size();k++)
      {
        if(temp_first==contacts[i].first_name&&temp_last==contacts[i].last_name)
            contacts[i].phone_number=new_phone;
    }
}
    for(int p=0;p>contacts.size();p++)
    {
       cout<<contacts[i].first_name<<" "<<contacts[i].last_name<<" "   <<contacts[i].phone_number<<endl;
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `vector <struct contact>` can just be `vector <contact>`

Answer (score 1):

The reason is a trivial typo in this loop:

```
for(int k=0;k<contacts.size();k++)
{
  if(temp_first==contacts[i].first_name&&temp_last==contacts[i].last_name)
    contacts[i].phone_number=new_phone;
}
```

It should be `contacts[k]` and not `contacts[i]`.

You have the same typo in the `for(int p...` loop. In addition, that loop condition should be `p < contacts.size()`.

This is an argument in favour of keeping the scope of variables, especially loop indices, as small as possible. Instead of declaring `int i` to be visible to the whole of `main`, keeping it limited to the `for` loop which used it would have allowed you to find this problem at compile-time.

Also, use C++11's [range-based for loops](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) whenever possible. For example, rewriting one of the above buggy loops using the new syntax,

```
for(auto& contact : contacts)
{
  if(temp_first==contact.first_name && temp_last==contact.last_name)
    contact.phone_number=new_phone;
}
```

Comment: i always have errors like that , what's your suggestions bro to come over it :(

Comment: @OmarKhaled Edited into the answer - keep loop indices local to the loop. You probably have the same typo in the `for(int p=0;` loop.

Comment: fixed.. but it is bugged in the first output

Comment: found it , wrong comparisons (uppercase and lower case prob) , advice me for getting over the logic errors problem , it is like headaches :(